# What is the best practice to check for pretty permalinks?

Tags: permalinks, feed

I develop a plugin and therefore I add new RSS feeds. One feed might look like `http://local.wordpress.dev/?post_type=custom-post-type&custom-taxonomy=tax-1&feed=custom-feed`

This works pretty good. But if pretty permalinks are enabled also this url works which will be redirect to the same feed `http://local.wordpress.dev/custom-taxonomy/tax-1/feed/custom-feed`.

So far so good. My plugin will list all available feeds for the user. My question what is the best practice to check if pretty permalinks are active and which url version should be displayed?

My idea is to look at `$wp_rewrite` which `permalink_structure` is set and decide which version to show. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 7):

The **Using Permalinks** page on WordPress.org tells you [how to check for the permalink structure](https://wordpress.org/support/article/using-permalinks/#check-for-permalink-structure):

```
if ( get_option('permalink_structure') ) { echo 'permalinks enabled'; }
```

The result will be an empty string if permalinks are default, otherwise you will get the permalink pattern though you should not have to worry much about the permalink details if you use Core functions to generate your links.

Comment: That answer was well hidden in the codex :) Thx for pointing this out.