# WordPress Multisite ABSPATH and get_home_path() to check for htaccess or web.config file

Tags: permalinks, multisite, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

Looking to update my WP Login Flow open source plugin to prevent using rewrite URLs in things like Lost Password, Login, Register, if the rewrite file does not exist on the server -- but need some help with multisite support.

From my understanding multisite installs will have just a single root `.htaccess` or `web.config` file, and rewrites are stored in the options table for sub-sites.

For now i'm using these functions below to check for rewrite file (and just return true now for multisite), but i would like to add support for checking multisites

```
function htaccess_exists(){
    if ( is_multisite() ) {
        return true;
    }

    // Ensure get_home_path() is declared.
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );

    $home_path     = get_home_path();
    $htaccess_file = $home_path . '.htaccess';
    return file_exists( $htaccess_file );
}

function iis_web_config_exists() {
    if ( is_multisite() ) {
        return true;
    }

    // Ensure get_home_path() is declared.
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    $home_path       = get_home_path();
    $web_config_file = $home_path . 'web.config';
    // iis7_supports_permalinks() also checks to make sure IIS7 or above (required for permalinks)
    return iis7_supports_permalinks() && file_exists( $web_config_file );
}
```

Maybe I can just try using `ABSPATH` for multisite to check for the files?

Any thoughts or suggestions on how I could accomplish this to work with multisite?

Comment: Looks like this was already answered here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144822/what-is-the-best-practice-to-check-for-pretty-permalinks

Comment: @NickCiske no that's completely different --- that's just checking if they are "enabled" and has nothing to do with actual `htaccess` or `web.config` files